# Controlling the X display manager service - on SLES 15

Tags: systemd, sles, gdm, display-manager

I'm not a fan of systemd, and have so far worked with systems which used SysVInit scripts (like Devuan); and upstart on older Ubuntu versions.

Now I'm "stuck" with a SLES 15 machine. I'm trying to figure out how to control its display manager service. I've figured out it's gdm - by looking at the process table - but `service --status-all` doesn't mention gdm, nor a display manager, nor anything of the sort. I see a file named `/usr/lib/systemd/system/display-manager.service`, but systemd doesn't seem to be aware of it.

So - how do I control my display manager with systemd, then?

Answer (score 0):

`service` is a legacy executable name. Use `systemctl` instead. For example:

```
systemctl stop display-manager
```

and

```
systemctl start display-manager
```

will work.